# mapping device memory and kernel allocated memory into the same vma

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm working on a driver where ranges of device memory are mapped into the user space (via IOCTL) for the application to write to. It works:

```
vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY;
vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTEXPAND;

down_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
ret = vm_iomap_memory(vma, from, sz_required);
up_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
```

where `from` is a physical address obtained from `pci_resource_start()` with some offset added to it.

The application also needs to read from the device so I increase the size of the region mmapped by application by `PAGE_SIZE`, allocate a page with `dma_alloc_coherent()`, and try to insert it at the end of the vma but that returns EBUSY. What do I do wrong? I should be able to stitch together multiple physical ranges into a single vma, both real memory and device mapped, or is that not supported?

In the new code a page is allocated like that, `dma_addr` is passed to the device so it knows where to write to:

```
dma = dma_alloc_coherent(&device, PAGE_SIZE, &dma_addr, GFP_KERNEL);
memset(dma, 0xfe, PAGE_SIZE);
set_memory_wb((unsigned long)dma, 1);
```

And the mapping code is changed to:

```
vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY;
vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTEXPAND;
vma->vm_flags |= VM_MIXEDMAP;

down_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
ret = vm_iomap_memory(vma, from, sz_required);
up_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

down_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
ret = vm_insert_page(vma, vma->vm_end - PAGE_SIZE, virt_to_page(dma));
up_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
```

The kernel is 4.15 on x86_64

Comment: Mapping DMA bus address to the system like regular memory sounds wrong. On top of that PCIe BAR usually about the addresses that may have side effects and `memremap()` APIs should be used. Last, but not least, update your old kernel to something better,

Comment: `from` points to device's DDR memory and driver has no interest in looking into what's written and it should be mapped uncached, I don't see how `memremap()` applies. Allocating coherent pages and letting device to write there also works on it's own. What doesn't work is stitching two physical ranges inside one vma. Finally, updating kernel isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: I see, good luck!

Comment: As far as I know, memory allocated by `dma_alloc_coherent` can only be mmaped using `dma_mmap_coherent`, which doesn't allow for stitching together "Frankenstein" VMAs from multiple parts.

Comment: I actually got to work by following advice from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851092/map-multiple-kernel-buffer-into-contiguous-userspace-buffer

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by following the "hack" in  [Map multiple kernel buffer into contiguous userspace buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851092/map-multiple-kernel-buffer-into-contiguous-userspace-buffer)

Before `vm_iomap_memory()` I decrement `vma->vm_end` by `PAGE_SIZE` and restore the old value afterwards. Also, I switched from `dma_alloc_coherent()` to `alloc_page()` following by `dma_map_page()`

Not the solution I'm satisfied with though. There has to be a better way, perhaps a fault handler in `vm_ops`? Although that seems counter-productive considering I know exactly what I will be mapping and where.

It appears to be working on x86_64 and aarch64